# GetTable in ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to make my LinQ statements to precompiled statements.

I'm using this guide: [LinQ opti](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X)

I construct the database connection like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserType> UserType { get; set; }
}
```

This Static class looks like this:

```
public static class clsCompiledQuery
{
    //UserType
    public static Func<ApplicationDbContext, string, IQueryable<UserType>>
        getUserTypeByCode = CompiledQuery.Compile((ApplicationDbContext db, string UserTypeCode)
            => from tbUserType in db.GetTable<UserType>()
              where tbUserType.UserTypeCode == "PAR"
                select tbUserType);

}
```

db.GetTable() is not available in ApplicationDbContext

Is there a way to create GetTable from ApplicationDbContext?

This is new ground for me, and I a bit lost in this area. 
The reason for this task/topic is LinQ is slow, and I need to find better performance.

Comment: Which version of EF and .net framework are you using?

Comment: EF 6.1.3, ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 Witch package do you refer to with .net framework?

Comment: .net framework is the "engine" you code runs in. I would guess you're using 4.5 or 4.6; Anyway it does not matter - look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `EF6` **queries are automatically compiled** regardless of the `.net framework` the code is running against.

The link you provided in your question is dated from 2009 when it made sense to pre-compile queries.

To give a little bit of history

- EF6 is the first version independent of the .net framework
- EF4 and EF5 can leverage the pre-compiled feature if running in framework 4.5+

Comment: Thanks.. Then I need to find other ways to optimize the dataaccess.. Any suggestions with EF6?

Comment: That's a BIG question. I'd say to look at entities tracking behaviour - you can turn them off if you're getting them and not updating them back.
Also have smaller contexts

Comment: I looking into denormalize some of the semi static parts of the database. It should give me a lot more performance, but also more complexity. Then I Output caching the static and semi static controllers in the MVC setup. The bundling and minification of the Javascript gave me 50% speed up on load times. The problem is still load time, and output caching is my friend here.